# Google Business API Locations Library

Tags: c#, google-api, google-my-business-api

I need to read/write location data to Google Business API. Unfortunately, it seems that Google provides the proper API wrapper only for Java:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/location-data

For instance,

```
public static void updateLocation(String phone, String name) throws Exception {
    Location location = new Location()
        .setPrimaryPhone(phone);

    Mybusiness.Accounts.Locations.Patch updateLocation =
        mybusiness.accounts().locations().patch(name, location);
    updateLocation.setFieldMask("primary_phone");
    updateLocation.setLanguageCode("en-AU");
    Location updatedLocation = updateLocation.execute();

    System.out.printf("Updated Location:\n%s", updatedLocation);
  }
```

I am looking for something similar for C#. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have not really used it, we ended up using another system, but there is a reference for plain REST so you can use any language and library https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/

Comment: please don't write link-only answers

Comment: Thanks, Jesper. Of cause REST is always an option. But I was thinking about the complete wrapper with appropriate models, etc. It is really strange that there is only Java implementation available